# Neo4j out of memory error when trying to return the number of nodes fitting a certain description

Tags: neo4j

The query in concern is:

```
MATCH (node:Wallet)
WHERE size((node)-[:SendTo]-()-[:SendTo]-())>0 or size(()-[:SendTo]-(node)-[:SendTo]-())>0
RETURN count(node)
```

The size of the database is 12.5 GB. The number of Wallet node is over 100000.

I tried to run the query with java over Eclipse with VM argument of `-Xmx28000m -Xms28000m -Xss9m` 
(I set the corresponding lines in neo4j.conf as well:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=28000m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=28000m
dbms.jvm.additional=-Xss4m
```

)

It will give the error of out of memory shortly after. The task manager shows that the corresponding program is using about 28 GB though. (It is a 64 bit computer with 32 GB RAM.)

Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to improve your predicates a bit. In one of those cases we can use the relationship store (which doesn't require expansion), in the other we might be able to use the exists() function.

Give this one a try.

```
MATCH (node:Wallet)
WHERE size((node)-[:SendTo]-()) >= 2 or exists((node)-[:SendTo*2]-())
RETURN count(node)
```